# Esconder div apos selecionar outra categoria

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Código do select

```
<select name="category" class="form-control" id="category">
                    <option value="">Escolha uma categoria</option>
                    <optgroup label="Vehicle">
                    <option value="2">Aircraft</option>
                    <option value="3">Automotive Items &amp; Parts</option>
                    <option value="4">Boats &amp; Watercraft</option>
                    <option value="5">Cars</option>
                    <option value="6">Classic Cars</option>
                    <option value="7">Commercial Trucks &amp; Tractor Trailers</option>
                    <option value="8">Off Road Vehicles</option>
                    <option value="9">RV &amp; Motorhomes</option>
                    <option value="10">SUVs</option>
                    <option value="11">Utility &amp; Work Trailers</option>
                    <option value="12">Vans</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="Sevices">
                    <option value="2">Automotive Services</option>
                    <option value="3">Beauty & Salon Services</option>
                    <option value="4">Caregivers & Baby Sitting</option>
                    <option value="5">Cleaning Services</option>
                    <option value="6">Construction & Remodeling</option>
                    <option value="7">Financial Services</option>
                    <option value="8">Health & Wellness</option>
                    <option value="9">Home Services</option>
                    <option value="10">Insurance</option>
                    <option value="11">Office Services</option>
                    <option value="12">Real Estate Services</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="Pets">
                    <option value="2">Birds</option>
                    <option value="3">Cats</option>
                    <option value="4">Dogs</option>
                    <option value="5">Fish & Reptile Pets</option>
                    <option value="6">Free Pets to Good Home</option>
                    <option value="7">Horses</option>
                    <option value="8">Pet Supplies</option>
                    </optgroup>
                  </select>
```

Pessoal a div abaixo só é exibida se selecionado a categoria x por exemplo

```
<div id="x">
  bla bla bla
</div>
```

Segue arquivo js

```
$("#x").hide();

$('#subcategorias').change(function(){
    var valor = $(this).val();
    if(valor){
        if(valor == 3){
            $("#x").show();
        }
    }else{
        $("#x").hide();
    }
});
```

Se eu trocar pra categoria "y" eu queria que abrisse a div referente a "y" mas escondesse a div "x".

Como eu faço isso?

Obrigado!

Comment: Poste o código do seu `select` também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode montar um `select` com os valores da `div` que você quer exibir e então utilizar as funções jQuery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) e [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) pra verificar qual o `value` selecionado e mostrar a `div` com mesmo `id` do valor selecionado, segue código de exemplo e demonstração:

```js
$('.div-sel').hide();

$('#seletor').on('change', function() {
  var selecionado = $(this).val();

  $('.div-sel').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == selecionado) {
      $(this).toggle();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#seletor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="seletor">
  <option value="">--- Departamentos ---</option>
  <option value="camisas">Camisas</option>
  <option value="calcas">Calças</option>
  <option value="acessorios">Acessórios</option>
</select>

<div id="camisas" class="div-sel">
  <ul>
    <li>Camisa 01</li>
    <li>Camisa 02</li>
    <li>Camisa 03</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="calcas" class="div-sel">
  <ul>
    <li>Calça 01</li>
    <li>Calça 02</li>
    <li>Calça 03</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="acessorios" class="div-sel">
  <ul>
    <li>Acessório 01</li>
    <li>Acessório 02</li>
    <li>Acessório 03</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Xará, funcionou do jeito que eu precisava.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia criar um array para indicar qual `div` deve ser exibida. Também seria uma boa idéia adicionar uma classe as `div`'s desejadas para poder ocultar sem mais dificuldades.

```
<div id="x" class="div-subcategoria">bla bla bla</div>
<div id="y" class="div-subcategoria">bla bla bla</div>
```

---

```
var divs = [];
divs[3] = "x";
divs[4] = "y";
// ...

$(".div-subcategoria").hide();

$('#subcategorias').change(function() {
    $(".div-subcategoria").hide();

    var valor = $(this).val();
    if (divs[valor]) {
        $("#" + divs[valor]).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou também

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo, claro, você vai precisar fazer algumas alterações de validações (se será por ID, ou outra coisa). Mas tenta essa lógica:

< div id="id_1" class="esconder">Div 1< /div>
 < div id="id_2" class="esconder">Div 2< /div>
 < div id="id_3" class="esconder">Div 3< /div>
 < div id="id_4" class="esconder">Div 4< /div>

```
<select id="sel" class="sel">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".esconder").hide();  
        $("#sel").on("change", function(e){
            var id = $(this).val(); 
            $(".esconder").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("id") == "id_"+id){
                    $(this).show();
                }
                else{
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou também

Answer (score 1):

A varias maneiras de se resolver isso. Utilizei esta função `toggle_visibility(id)` que recebe o id de um elemento html, e alterna o estado do elemento `display` entre `block` e `none` e construi a `toggle()` de maneira a alternar a visibilidade de todos os elementos no meu html.

Assim a cada clique no meu botão Mudar, o elemetno `display` seja alterado

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggle_visibility(id) 
        {
            var e = document.getElementById(id);
            if ( e.style.display == 'block' )
                e.style.display = 'none';
            else
                e.style.display = 'block';
        }
        function toggle(){
            toggle_visibility('portfolio');
            toggle_visibility('results') ;
        }
    </script>


    <button onclick="toggle()" >Mudar</button> 


    <div class="visible" id="portfolio" style="display:block">
        <span>div1</span>
    </div>

    <div class"hidden" id="results"style="display:none">
        <span>div2</span>
    </div>
```

**EDIT**

A lógica poderia ser alterada para se adequar a uma quantidade maior de divs.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var vetor = new Array ("vehicle2", "vehicle3", "vehicle4", "vehicle5", "vehicle6", "vehicle7");



        function show(){
        var e = document.getElementById('category');

        console.log(e.value);

            for (i=0; i < vetor.length; i++){
                document.getElementById(vetor[i]).style.display = 'none';
            }               
            document.getElementById(e.value).style.display = 'block';
        }

    </script>

    <select name="category" class="form-control" id="category" onchange="show();">
                <option value="">Escolha uma categoria</option>
                <optgroup label="Vehicle">
                <option value="vehicle2">Aircraft</option>
                <option value="vehicle3">Automotive Items &amp; Parts</option>
                <option value="vehicle4">Boats &amp; Watercraft</option>
                <option value="vehicle5">Cars</option>
                <option value="vehicle6">Classic Cars</option>
                <option value="vehicle7">Commercial Trucks &amp; Tractor Trailers</option>
                <option value="vehicle8">Off Road Vehicles</option>
                <option value="vehicle9">RV &amp; Motorhomes</option>
                <option value="vehicle10">SUVs</option>
                <option value="vehicle11">Utility &amp; Work Trailers</option>
                <option value="vehicle12">Vans</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Sevices">
                <option value="sevices2">Automotive Services</option>
                <option value="sevices3">Beauty & Salon Services</option>
                <option value="sevices4">Caregivers & Baby Sitting</option>
                <option value="sevices5">Cleaning Services</option>
                <option value="sevices6">Construction & Remodeling</option>
                <option value="sevices7">Financial Services</option>
                <option value="sevices8">Health & Wellness</option>
                <option value="sevices9">Home Services</option>
                <option value="sevices10">Insurance</option>
                <option value="sevices11">Office Services</option>
                <option value="sevices12">Real Estate Services</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Pets">
                <option value="pets2">Birds</option>
                <option value="pets3">Cats</option>
                <option value="pets4">Dogs</option>
                <option value="pets5">Fish & Reptile Pets</option>
                <option value="pets6">Free Pets to Good Home</option>
                <option value="pets7">Horses</option>
                <option value="pets8">Pet Supplies</option>
                </optgroup>
              </select>


    <div   id="vehicle2" style="display:none"  >
        <span>div1 Aircraft</span>
    </div>

    <div  id="vehicle3"style="display:none" >
        <span>div2 Automotive</span>
    </div>

    <div  id="vehicle4"style="display:none" >
        <span>div3 Boats</span>
    </div>

    <div  id="vehicle5"style="display:none" >
        <span>div3 Cars</span>
    </div>

    <div  id="vehicle6"style="display:none" >
        <span>div3 Classic Cars</span>
    </div>

    <div  id="vehicle7"style="display:none" >
        <span>div3 Commercial Trucks &amp; Tractor Trailers</span>
    </div>
```

Modifiquei o elemento `value` do seu select para que cada opção tenha um valor único. Dessa forma você pode vincular o valor selecionado diretamente ao `id` da div.

Usando `document.getElementById('category').value` você tem acesso ao valor selecionado e pode exibir a div desejada.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou também

Answer (score 1):

Não sei como está seu select, mas acredito que isso funcionaria para você:

### EDIT:

Aplicando agora a sua realidade, acredito se encaixar para você:

```js
$("#1").hide();
$("#2").hide();
$("#3").hide();
var lastOpen = '';
$('#category').on('change', function (e) {
    var input = '#' + $(this).val();
    if ($(input).length) {
        $(input).show();
        $(lastOpen).hide();
        lastOpen = input;
    } else {
        $(lastOpen).hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">XXXXXXXXXX</div>
<div id="2">222222</div>
<div id="3">zzzzzzzzzz</div>
<select name="category" class="form-control" id="category">
<option value="">Escolha uma categoria</option>
<optgroup label="Vehicle">
    <option value="2">Aircraft</option>
    <option value="3">Automotive Items &amp; Parts</option>
    <option value="4">Boats &amp; Watercraft</option>
    <option value="5">Cars</option>
    <option value="6">Classic Cars</option>
    <option value="7">Commercial Trucks &amp; Tractor Trailers</option>
    <option value="8">Off Road Vehicles</option>
    <option value="9">RV &amp; Motorhomes</option>
    <option value="10">SUVs</option>
    <option value="11">Utility &amp; Work Trailers</option>
    <option value="12">Vans</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Sevices">
    <option value="2">Automotive Services</option>
    <option value="3">Beauty & Salon Services</option>
    <option value="4">Caregivers & Baby Sitting</option>
    <option value="5">Cleaning Services</option>
    <option value="6">Construction & Remodeling</option>
    <option value="7">Financial Services</option>
    <option value="8">Health & Wellness</option>
    <option value="9">Home Services</option>
    <option value="10">Insurance</option>
    <option value="11">Office Services</option>
    <option value="12">Real Estate Services</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Pets">
    <option value="2">Birds</option>
    <option value="3">Cats</option>
    <option value="4">Dogs</option>
    <option value="5">Fish & Reptile Pets</option>
    <option value="6">Free Pets to Good Home</option>
    <option value="7">Horses</option>
    <option value="8">Pet Supplies</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Qualquer dúvida ou caso não seja o que deseja por favor avise;

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou também

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você precisa exibir a `div` da categoria e subcategoria, sendo assim:

```js
$('#category').change(function(){
   $('.group').hide(); // oculta qualquer div group
   $('.sub').hide(); // oculta qualquer div sub
   var group ='#'+ $(this.options[this.selectedIndex])
   .closest('optgroup').prop('label'); //grupo que será exibido
   var val = $(this).val(); // Valor do option 
   $(group).show(); // exibe a div de grupos
   $('.sub[data-value='+val+']').show(); // exibe a div da subcategoria
});
```

```css
.group{display:none;}
.sub{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="category" class="form-control" id="category">
     <option value="">Escolha uma categoria</option>
     <optgroup label="Vehicle">
         <option value="2">Aircraft</option>
         <option value="3">Automotive Items &amp; Parts</option>
     </optgroup>
     <optgroup label="Sevices">
          <option value="2">Automotive Services</option>
          <option value="3">Beauty & Salon Services</option>
     </optgroup>
</select>
<div class="group" id="Vehicle">
    <h3>Vehicle</h3>
    <div class="sub" data-value="2">Aircraft</div>
    <div class="sub" data-value="3">Automotive Items &amp; Parts</div>
</div>

<div class="group" id="Sevices">
    <h3>Sevices</h3>
    <div class="sub" data-value="2">Automotive Services</div>
    <div class="sub" data-value="3">Beauty & Salon Services</div>
</div>
```

**OBS: Esta é uma sugestão de implementação, tudo depende da estrutura de seu HTML, divs e etc.**

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou também